# make a column which conditional count

Tags: r

I'm new to r, and having some difficulties with this simple task.
I have dataset of prices within many retailers.
I would like to count how many prices changes in other store in the time interval of setting the price and changing it.

(df edited, based on Len Greski answer)

```
id<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
startdate<-c("01/01/2017", "05/01/2017", "13/01/2017", "10/01/2017", 
"01/02/2017" , "20/01/2017")
startdate<-as.POSIXct(strptime(startdate,"%d/%m/%Y"))
enddate<-c("10/01/2017","01/02/2017","20/01/2017","05/02/2017",
"06/02/2017","31/01/2017")
enddate<-as.POSIXct(strptime(enddate,"%d/%m/%Y"))
price<-runif(6,1,10)
item<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a")
result<-c(1,3,0,3,1,0)
```

I tried to do it in many way, I didn't find any way that does the job. Is there any straightforward solution for that?

I've tried few methods,
I think that the first is closer to get what I want

1)

`df<-mutate(df, counter=nrow(df[df$startdate > startime & df$endtime<endtime]))`

2)

`lapply(df, function(startimei=df$startdate, endtimeri=df$endtime, itemi=df$item) {
sum(df$startdate > startimei & df$endtime<endtimei & df$item==itemi)
} )`

Thankya all!

Comment: You define `price` but you create your data.frame with `p`

Comment: Both attempts that you propose lead to errors in base R. What packages have you loaded?

Comment: Can You give an elaboration of what you mean?

Comment: about the p and price- you re right. it should be the same. anyway I don't take it into account in that  part of that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach with the `sqldf` package.

```
id<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
startdate<-c("01/01/2017", "05/01/2017", "13/01/2017", "10/01/2017", 
             "01/02/2017" , "20/01/2017")
startdate<-as.POSIXct(strptime(startdate,"%d/%m/%Y"))
enddate<-c("10/01/2017","01/02/2017","20/01/2017","05/02/2017","06/02/2017","31/01/2017")
enddate<-as.POSIXct(strptime(enddate,"%d/%m/%Y"))
price<-runif(6,1,10)
item<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a")
result<-c(1,3,0,3,1,0)

df<-data.frame(item,id,startdate,enddate,price,result)
library(sqldf)
sqlStmt <- "select a.item, a.id,a.startdate, a.enddate, b.id as changedId, b.startdate as changedDate 
            from df as a 
            inner join  df as b
            on a.item = b.item and a.id != b.id and (b.startdate between a.startdate and a.enddate) "


priceChanges <- sqldf(sqlStmt)
priceChanges$changedDate <- 
as.POSIXct(priceChanges$changedDate,origin="1970-01-01")
priceChanges
```

The output shows the product ids and dates on which the other products changed.

```
> priceChanges
  item id  startdate    enddate changedId changedDate
1    a  1 2017-01-01 2017-01-10         2  2017-01-05
2    a  2 2017-01-05 2017-02-01         1  2017-01-10
3    a  2 2017-01-05 2017-02-01         3  2017-01-13
4    a  2 2017-01-05 2017-02-01         3  2017-01-20
5    a  1 2017-01-10 2017-02-05         2  2017-02-01
6    a  1 2017-01-10 2017-02-05         3  2017-01-13
7    a  1 2017-01-10 2017-02-05         3  2017-01-20
>
```

To calculate number of price changes by product and startdate, we can use another SQL query.

```
> sqlStmt <- "select item, id, startdate, count(*) as count from 
priceChanges
+                  group by item,id,startdate"
> priceChangeCounts <- sqldf(sqlStmt)
> priceChangeCounts
   item id  startdate count
 1    a  1 2017-01-01     1
 2    a  1 2017-01-10     3
 3    a  2 2017-01-05     3
 >
```

Finally, we merge the original data with the summarized counts and recode missing values to 0 so they can be used in subsequent analyses.

```
sqlStmt <- "select a.*, b.count from df as a
             left join priceChangeCounts as b
             on a.item = b.item and a.id = b.id and a.startdate = b.startdate"
mergedData <- sqldf(sqlStmt)
mergedData[is.na(mergedData[,"count"]),"count"] <- 0
mergedData
```

...and the output.

```
> mergedData
  item id  startdate    enddate    price result count
1    a  1 2017-01-01 2017-01-10 6.484062      1     1
2    a  2 2017-01-05 2017-02-01 9.410354      3     3
3    a  3 2017-01-13 2017-01-20 5.656238      0     0
4    a  1 2017-01-10 2017-02-05 8.542557      3     3
5    a  2 2017-02-01 2017-02-06 1.769380      0     0
6    a  3 2017-01-20 2017-01-31 8.280155      0     0
>
```

Please note that the data in the OP for the `result` column is wrong, as `id=2`, `startdate=2017-02-01` has no other price changes from other ids where the start date of a new price is between 2017-02-01 and 2017-02-06.

Comment: Hi Len, thx for your help.
can SQL leave line with zeros as well?

At the end of the day the purpose of this is to run a regression with the count as one of the predictors. so 0 has a lot of meaning and taking it out will remove many obs fro, the data set.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck - Updated. I was aware that strings could run across multiple lines, but hadn't connected it with the SQL statement. Thanks for making the connection for me.

Comment: @OrA - one can merge the rows from the original data frame back into the summarized price change counts, and recode the missing counts to 0. I'll update the post to include the additional steps.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found an easier solution that should work:

```
id<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
startdate<-c("01/01/2017", "05/01/2017", "13/01/2017", "10/01/2017", "01/02/2017" , "20/01/2017")
startdate<-as.POSIXct(strptime(startdate,"%d/%m/%Y"))
enddate<-c("10/01/2017","01/02/2017","20/01/2017","05/02/2017","06/02/2017","31/01/2017")
enddate<-as.POSIXct(strptime(enddate,"%d/%m/%Y"))
p<-runif(6,1,10)
item<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a")
result<-c(1,3,0,3,0,0)
df<-data.frame(item,id,startdate,enddate,p,result)


for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  a<-df$startdate[i]
  b<-df$enddate[i]
  df$counter[i]<-nrow(subset(df,(df$startdate< b&
                                 df$startdate> a)))

}
```

Comment: if your data includes thousands of products and hundreds of stores, this approach will take a lot of compute time because it rereads `df` once per row to subset the data, and reads the result to calculate `nrow()`. For example: 1000 products, 100 stores and an average of 2 price changes per month per product / store, one year's worth of data would be 2,400,000 rows. In this scenario your code would reread `df` 2.4 million times. I'd have to generate a large volume of test data to compare processing times, but I believe the SQL solution will run faster than the `for()` loop solution.

Comment: You are right,
insted I subseted by items, and than ran this piece of code.